# How to create the first contact created on account to become primary contact?

Tags: apex, trigger

My problem is this:

If an Account has no Contacts, then the first created contact by default becomes the primary and that value should be set in reference. If the primary contact is deleted, the next available contact, if there is any, should be the primary contact and the relationship on account should reflect this. If all contacts are deleted, the primary contact reference on Account will be blanked out.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class CreatePrimaryContactHandler {
    public static void createPrimary(List<Account> accounts){
      Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
      List<Account> updatedAccounts = new List<Account>();
      List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
      for (Contact c : con) {
        accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
      }
       Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id, Primary_Contact__c, (Select Id, Name from Contacts where IsPrimary__c = true) from Account where Id in :accountIds]);
        for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.IsPrimary && accountMap.get(c.AccountId)) {
            Account updAccount = accountMap.get(c.AccountId);
            updAccount.Primary_Contact__c = c.Id;
            if (updAccount.Contacts != null && updAccount.Contacts.size()>0) { // This will identify if account already has primary contact set
              // Not sure what you want to do? Throw an error? or turn off the iS Primary on older contact?
            }

            updatedAccounts.add(updAccount);
        } 
      }

      update updatedAccounts;
    }

}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger CreatePrimaryContact on Contact (after insert, after update){
    CreatePrimaryContactHandler.createPrimary();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, what specific problem or error are you having with this code? Could you edit your question to clarify what you need?

Comment: The scenario is when the account has no current contacts, the first contact created will be the one to become primary contact. By the way the code is not mine.

Comment: The objective is clear, but we just have an objective statement and a block of code here. What is the [specific issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) with this code, with which you'd like assistance? How is it not meeting the requirements? What error are you grappling with?