# Anyone can optimized this code for better explanation and easy to understand?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, unit-test, dml

The function of this apex code is when Account has no Contacts the first contact created become the primary contact and when there is existing primary contact it cannot assign a other primary contact on account.
Please help to optimized my code to easy understand.Thanks for the help.

```
public class CreatePrimaryContactHandler
{
    public static void createPrimary(List<Contact> contactList)
    {
       Set<Id> accountId = new Set<Id>();
        for(Contact c : contactList)
        {
            accountId.add(c.AccountId);
        }
        List<Contact> allContact = [SELECT Id, Account.Id, Primary_Contact__c FROM Contact WHERE (Account.Id IN : accountId)];
        Map<Id, List<Contact>> acctContactMap = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
            for(Id aId : accountId)
            {
             List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
                for(Contact allcont : allContact)
                {
                    if(allcont.AccountId == aId)
                    {
                    conList.add(allcont);
                    }
                }
                acctContactMap.put(aId, conList);
            }
            for(Id accId : acctContactMap.keySet())
            {
                Integer count = 0;
                for(Contact c : contactList)
                {
                    if(c.AccountId == accId && c.Primary_Contact__c)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(count <= 1)
                {
                    List<Contact> cList = acctContactMap.get(accId);
                    Contact primary;
                    Boolean isPrimary = false;
                    for(Contact cont : cList)
                    {
                        if(cont.Primary_Contact__c)
                        {
                            isPrimary = true;
                        }
                    }
                    for(Contact cont : contactList)
                    {
                        if(cont.AccountId == accId)
                        {
                            if(cont.Primary_Contact__c)
                            {
                                if(primary != null)
                                {
                                    primary.Primary_Contact__c = false;
                                     isPrimary = false;
                                }
                                else if(isPrimary)
                                {
                                cont.addError('Invalid Primary Contact. This Account has already an existing Primary Contact.');
                                }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        cont.Primary_Contact__c = true;
                                        isPrimary = true;
                                    }
                            }   
                                else if(!isPrimary)
                                {
                                    cont.Primary_Contact__c = true;
                                    isPrimary = true;
                                    primary = cont;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    contactList.get(0).addError('Invalid Primary Contact. This Account has already an existing Primary Contact.');
                }
        }  
    }
}
```

This is the Trigger

```
trigger CheckPrimaryContact on Contact (before insert,after update,before update){
    if(trigger.IsInsert && trigger.IsBefore){
        CreatePrimaryContactHandler.createPrimary(trigger.new);
    }
    if(trigger.IsBefore && trigger.IsUpdate){
        CreatePrimaryContactHandler.createPrimary(trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it differ from your previous question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245740/how-to-create-the-first-contact-created-on-account-to-become-primary-contact

Comment: @Reshma, This code is working not like the previous question I'm a total beginner on salesforce coding so I want to better understand the code. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you meant by _not working_?

Comment: I mean I replaced the previous one with this.

Comment: I understand that. What's the issue you are facing with the current code?

Comment: I just want to know if the current code can be optimized?

Comment: Your code can be optimise. Please go through [Apex Code Best Practise](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) and learn by yourself

Comment: If you are a total beginner, you will have a much better time both here and overall with your learning experience if you first work your way through as many **Trailhead** modules as you can find which are relevant to your interests. The format here is *specific* questions and answers, and you will better utilize this site if you possess more baseline skills. The Trailhead was designed to do the kind of hand holding you may still need as a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you some tips on how to optimse.

1. Use `AccountId` instead of `Account.Id` in query
2. Use Map to get results and avoid multiple collection variables and loops

So you can replace the below code block by one line.

```
List<Contact> allContact = [SELECT Id, Account.Id, Primary_Contact__c FROM Contact WHERE (Account.Id IN : accountId)];
Map<Id, List<Contact>> acctContactMap = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
for(Id aId : accountId)
{
 List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Contact allcont : allContact)
    {
        if(allcont.AccountId == aId)
        {
        conList.add(allcont);
        }
    }
    acctContactMap.put(aId, conList);
}
```

Use [Map of sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm) and replace the above lines by:

```
Map<Id, Account> acctContactMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, AccountId, Primary_Contact__c FROM Contacts) WHERE Id IN :accountId]);
```

Understand your logic and optimise the remaining based on [Apex code best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)